Customized mail-merge for google sheet exceeds Gmail API's limit
I got the app script generated by the chatGPT.
I wanted the following to be done through the app script:

I have created 5 drafts. The sheet has a code that would replace {{code}} from the subject; name column will replace {{Name}} from the body. Will read the drafts and send the email to the email address

This email will be triggered only when I select any of the 5 dropdown options in the sheet. Each drop down options have exactly the same name as the subject of the draft.


Problem:
Even though this code runs, after one or two email, Gmail API hits limitation.
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var drafts = cacheDrafts(); // Cache drafts to reduce API calls

  if (drafts === null) {
    Logger.log('Too many drafts to cache in one day. Try again later.');
    return;
  }

  // Process emails in batches to avoid hitting Gmail API limits
  var batchSize = 50; // Adjust batch size as needed
  for (var start = 1; start < data.length; start += batchSize) {
    var end = Math.min(start + batchSize, data.length);
    processBatch(data.slice(start, end), drafts, sheet, start);
    Utilities.sleep(1000); // Pause between batches to avoid hitting rate limits
  }
}

function processBatch(batchData, drafts, sheet, startIndex) {
  for (var i = 0; i < batchData.length; i++) {
    var row = batchData[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2]; // Assuming column A is Email
    var name = row[1]; // Assuming column B is Name
    var templateName = row[10]; // Assuming column C is Template
    var code = row[0]; // Assuming column D is Code
    
    if (templateName) {
      var draft = getDraftByTemplateName(templateName, drafts);
      if (draft) {
        var personalizedBody = draft.body.replace('{{Name}}', name);
        var personalizedSubject = draft.subject.replace('{{Code}}', code);
        
        try {
          GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, personalizedSubject, '', {
            htmlBody: personalizedBody,
            attachments: draft.attachments
          });
          sheet.getRange(startIndex + i + 1, 10).setValue(''); // Clear the template selection after sending the email
        } catch (e) {
          Logger.log('Failed to send email: ' + e.toString());
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log('No draft found for template: ' + templateName);
      }
    }
  }
}

function cacheDrafts() {
  var maxDraftsToCache = 20; // Limit the number of drafts to cache in one run
  try {
    var drafts = GmailApp.getDrafts();
    var draftCache = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(drafts.length, maxDraftsToCache); i++) {
      var draft = drafts[i].getMessage();
      var subject = draft.getSubject();
      draftCache[subject] = {
        body: draft.getBody(),
        subject: draft.getSubject(),
        attachments: draft.getAttachments()
      };
    }
    return draftCache;
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Failed to cache drafts: ' + e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}

function getDraftByTemplateName(templateName, draftCache) {
  for (var subject in draftCache) {
    if (subject.includes(templateName)) { // Check if subject includes the template name
      return draftCache[subject];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

I did not try anything. I am yet to determine the root cause. Since I did not write the script myself, I am having trouble identifying and fixing it.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The site AI Policy prohibits posting code generated by ChatGPT. Instead of posting that code add a [mcve] created by you.

This question is similar to: Google Suite App Script Email Sending Limit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
